# Are there any real lyrics to Sunn O)))'s "Why Dost Thou Hide Thyself In Clouds"?

Tags: lyrics, prog-rock, prog-metal, black-metal

I've listened to [the whole song](https://youtu.be/qCfu4XK3M_0) several times now despite its duration. Atilla Csihar's vocals are probably my favourite part, even if they are a theoretical disaster. It reminds me of some sort of Christian mystic/Gnostic ritual. Anyway, the Internet seems to be of little help on this one. **Are there any real lyrics?** I do believe I heard "It calls" at one point but I could be mistaken. Can you make out anything else?

Comment: The title comes (presumably) from the William Blake poem ["To Nobodaddy"](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/To_Nobodaddy), but it's not clear those are the words being sung. I tried a few different translations (Norwegian, Hungarian, German, Icelandic, and Latin), but none seemed to fit. See also the [Neal Young song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIWkkIqOoxk) of the same title.

Comment: The lyrics are credited to the band members (this might be wrong but this is what is registered in the ISWC databases). Between [8:00 and 9:15](https://youtu.be/qCfu4XK3M_0?t=481) several words sound English to me ("my entire life", "sister", "it crawls" -your "it calls"?-, "disappear"), but I'm not a native speaker. If it is not gibberish, then maybe is it Hungarian since the singer is from Hungary.